# Google Contacts - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.of([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet;

Tags: java, guava, gdata, google-contacts-api

POM.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>****</groupId>
        <artifactId>****</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>web</artifactId>

    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>web</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

         DB Connection Pooling -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SPRING -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate Validator -->
        <!-- Form Validation using Annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude SLF4j to avoid version conflicts (we have 1.6.2, this drags 
                    in 1.6.1) -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- TILES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
            <version>${tiles-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- CGLIB is required to process @Configuration classes -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet API and JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- LOGGING -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>common</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>service</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-service</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>dao</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-dao</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>model</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-model</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Apache Commons Upload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-fileupload}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons Upload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-io}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.tanesha.recaptcha4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>recaptcha4j</artifactId>
            <version>${recapchta.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gdata</groupId>
             <artifactId>core</artifactId>
              <version>1.47.1</version>
        <dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openengsb.wrapped</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.google.gdata-contacts</artifactId>
            <version>1.41.5.w1</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependencies>
</project>
```

And I am getting an exception when I am trying following piece of code :

```
private ContactsService authenticateId(String userid, String password) {

        ContactsService contactService = null;
        try {
            contactService = new ContactsService("exampleCo-exampleApp-1");
            contactService.setUserCredentials(userid, password);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return contactService;

    }
```

exception :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.of([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet;
    at com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltFormat$Builder.setAcceptableTypes(AltFormat.java:399)
    at com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltFormat$Builder.setAcceptableXmlTypes(AltFormat.java:387)
    at com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltFormat.<clinit>(AltFormat.java:49)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.<clinit>(Service.java:558)
```

In my .m2 folder I can see it is fetching many version of guava as I may have other dependencies like gson which I guess is also using guava.

Tried to add a dependency externally for guava r07, but didn't work.

Same code works like a charm in my POC example, where in that POM only two maven dependencies related to gdata was added.

Comment: I think you need to post a pom file and java class - i.e. reduce the problem - that others can use to reproduce the error in order to get assistance here.

Comment: Added full pom and java code snippet.

Answer (score 5):

I think that you have a problem described in [this bug report](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/issues/detail?id=344)

> It is very dangerous to use google-collect.jar, as if a user ends up
>   with that and guava on her classpath at the same time, very
>   unpredictable and strange errors can result.

Other libraries declared in your pom (probably GSON) implicitly add Guava to your classpath. And you are just experiencing these "unpredictable and strange errors" ;-)

Someone on StackOverflow had [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475015/nosuchmethoderror-google-common-immutableset-copyof). Maybe you could do the same that he did, i.e. explicitly declare rc05 version of Guava to force maven to use this one? (see: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3937255/713937))

Comment: I added guava rc05/rc07 explicitly in pom, and commented GSON, GDATA and all other libraries related to google, still it is downloading Guava 10, 11, 12, 13 (all four version) in .m2 folder. Not sure the dependency tree for that.

Comment: So try: `mvn dependency:tree` to debug it.

Answer (score 2):

```
   Try adding below exclusion in tiles. 

   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
        <version>${tiles-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```